# Creating a java programming to webpage source code with user input file name

Tags: java

I' m trying to work on my program which is capturing the source code into file. I trying a different way to make it work but it seem to be not working. For example i wanted to capture the webpage source code and allowing user to save the program into .txt format. could anyone help me with it? `

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;


public class ReadFromWeb {
    public static void readFromWeb(String webURL) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(webURL); // create a new url 
        InputStream is =  url.openStream(); //input 

        //read url 
        try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) { 
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MalformedURLException("URL is malformed!!");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IOException();
        }

    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner login = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner cn= new Scanner(System.in); //create case name scaner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // create the scanner for capture webpage

        String Username;
        String Password;

        Username = "steven";
        Password = "1234";

        System.out.println("enter username : ");
        String username = login.next();

        System.out.println("enter password : ");
        String password= login.next();

        if (username.equals(Username)&& (password.equals(Password))){
           System.out.println("logged in");



        //create file name and save file

        System.out.println("enter case number :"  );
        String input = cn.nextLine().trim();
        File file = new File(input);

        file.createNewFile();

        //write into file
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);



        System.out.println("enter URL : ");
        String print;
        String url = sc.nextLine();  // read the URL
        readFromWeb(url); //show the url source data
       // writer.write(print); //write into file
       // writer.close(); //write close
        }
        else if (username.equals(Username)){ //invalid password

            System.out.println ("invalid password");

        }
        else if (password.equals(Password)){ //invalid username
            System.out.println("Invalid username");

    }
        else { //invalid bth username and password
            System.out.println("invalid username & password");
            System.exit(0);
        }



}
}
```

`

so basically the program required the user to login, and then the file name will be equally to the case no that the user input. after that, user paste the url and the system will be capturing it and save it into the file. but what could work is that i couldn't save the file into the filename that the user input.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please see also: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Now, you seem to have a good start with your code already. What exactly is the difficulty you are facing now?

Comment: i get the file name by the user input. but i tried this way and it does not work and dint save into the file with the file name that input by the user. while it successful read it.

Comment: You should show what exactly you have tried and which errors/exception did you get (incl. stacktrace).

Comment: You only show the Code to read the Page, not how to save it.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at ReadFromWeb.main(ReadFromWeb.java:77) 


this was the part when i tried to bring the soruce code in with "writer.write(readFromWeb(url))" . it work fine with just scanner in.

Comment: yeah the code is only show the source code. but i wanted to save it into the file. so that i can open the source code anywhere i wan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not even trying to write something to the output file.

I see three possible solutions:

#### 1. Let your method write the output

For this, change the name of your `readFromWeb` to `download` and declare a second argument, which takes your `File`. Then let the while loop write the `line` to the file, instead to `stdout`.

Pros:

- Small memory footprint (maximum size of a line)

Cons:

- No good separation of concerns, since your method does *both*

#### 2. Let your method return the content and write it to a file

Instead of writing the lines to `stdout`, append them with a `StringBuilder` to one big fat `String` and return it from your method (don't forget to add the line breaks manually).

Pros:

- Separation of concerns (read from web / output to file)

Cons:

- One big buffer (not very good for large files)

#### 3. <strike>Return</strike> Use the line stream

Instead of processing the lines in your method via a `while` loop, use the lines stream obtained by the `BufferedReader`s `lines()` method. Then use `forEach()` with the `println()` method of a `PrintWrite` (you need to put your `FileWriter` in there - this is necessary, because `append()` doesn't give you the line breaks).

Pros:

- Use of functional concepts which make your intention clear
- Again, no big buffer required

Cons:

- Read / Write is also not separated in this approach
- There are still better ways to do this, but this should make you happy.

*Update*: Since the original idea requires a more complex management of the `BufferedReader` instance, I updated the answer to directly use the lines stream within the method.

Comment: so you mean that i need a reader for the method? is it something like i bufferreader it and  open a while loop with it?

Comment: @YuhengLim I updated variant 3 to make it easier for you. Just pass your `FileWriter` as an argument to your method, and use it to write your data line by line.